# .htaccess rewrite ErrorDocument not being redirected

Tags: php, .htaccess

I removed the `php` directory from my URL and remove the .php extension.
But now I am trying to add my 404/500 error to make my website look nice.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /php/$1 [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
```

When I redirect the errorDocument to an external page it works but not to my local file. I get a `500 Internal Server error`. I could make a workaround and just make it go to an external page what will be my page. But that's not really clean.
Is anyone able to help me with this?

Comment: Looks like an infinite rewrite when e.g. `/php/$1` is not present, then `/php/php/$1` aso. I prefer the `FallbackResource` of the `mod_dir`, then routing in PHP. Avoiding `mod_rewrite` at all is much more performant.

Comment: what is /php/ ? is it directory ? and what will be happened when wrong request goes there ?

Comment: `I removed the php directory`, but your rewrite rule adds it in `/php/$1`. What  does the logs say about 500 server error?

Comment: @vivek_23 I am trying to remove the /php/ from my url with it. Not the right way of doing it?

Comment: @MohammedElhag yea it's a directory. If you go there it works like a normal directory

Comment: @Tygo did you try my solution below ? let me know the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must match against `DOCUMENT_ROOT` as well as add this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` before adding `.php` like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/php%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
# or you could do it like this 
# RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/php%{REQUEST_URI} -f
# without php according to your setting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /php/$1 [QSA,L]


ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
```

because whenever you send wrong request to any target destination you must make sure that target will handle it and there are enough conditions to classify which one should go , otherwise server will generate  error.